# ms excel - option to show all the cells (AA,AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,AI etc.,)

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I have an microsoft excel sheet which is doing some calculation using VBA.
I enabled "Show formulas" and I could see in one of the cell the formula is shown as **"=AI38*AO34"**.
But I am not able to see the AI cell in my excel sheet . After "Z" , I have "AA" and then "AB".
Then it contineous with "AW" and "AX" and so on.

How to check the AD to rest of the cells . The cells are not hidden in this sheet.

Please let me know the option to show all the cells.

Thanks

Comment: Select columns `Z:BB`, right-click the heading, set width to 50. A column is considered "hidden" when its width is 0.

Answer (score 1):

May be cells width are collapsed.You can try that select all cells with Ctrl+A and  select mouse left click on AB and extend them much more.
So you can see all your cells.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub UnHideMyColumns()
    Cells.ColumnWidth = 10
End Sub
```

It just sets all column widths to 10. You can add Columns.AutoFit if you want to add more to it.

If you are not up on your VBA, select the columns around what you want to increase and change the width of ANY columns to a non-zero amount (just drag right) and it'll change all the columns between the selected columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't understand why you tagged it with `vba` and `excel-vba`.

Second, try to UNHIDE the invisible cells (or change the columns width).

Comment: The cell is not hidden . I tried with UNHIDE. It uses vba , hence i tagged a s VBA.

Comment: Look, if a column is not being shown (say, column "Z"), it is either hidden or its width is near 0.

Comment: I agree with the second point.  I am curious as to your confusion on the first, I understood this was normal practice.  See the most upvoted vba question on SO for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops